# When good time to start another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have an Android Best Practice question. I have to following code, which is working nicely, but I think it is not so elegant. So, my question is: at which point of activity life cycle is nice to start another activity ?

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ParentPreferences parentPreferences = new ParentPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    if (parentPreferences.isPassExists()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }
 }
}
```

The task is about: if the parent has already made a password to protect the app, than we don't need to show the LoginActivity. I don't know, is it "healthy" for an Activity to give an intent to launch, when nor the onCreate nor the other lifecycle methods completed.

What are you thoughts guys ?

Comment: don't forget to finish() your LoginActivity

Comment: Thx! Why finish needed here ? What if I don't add finish, but I have noHistory in manifest ?

Comment: noHistory takes care of it

Comment: Romain Guy, if you can read this, when Google parsed, it would be nice to jump here and provide a professional solution :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the better way is to create LauncherActivity, and start activitys from them:

For example:

```
      public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ParentPreferences parentPreferences = new ParentPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Intent intent;
        if (parentPreferences.isPassExists()) {
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);

        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
        startActivity(i);
     }
    }
```

**Updated:**
Refering to [Activity | Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[image]

onCreate is a first lifecycle method, сonsequently better to start activity B when A activity just started and does not inflate any layout

Comment: hm, I agree. Your solution is a bit nicer, but still harming or not harming (this is my question about) the LauncherActivity, because we launching another activities from onCreate.

Comment: Launch activity from onCreate is the best practice

Comment: Thank you Sergey! May I kindly ask to explain why or give some link to official docs ? If you do, please add as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the manifest start your MainActivity or whatever you call it. The MainActivity starts by checking if the user has logged in. If not, it starts your LoginActivity, which comes back in onActivityResult() with the result of the login. 
It does depend on the requirement for the user to log in every time they start the app, or just once, or once in a while. If the use has to log in every time, than it's ok to start with LoginActivity. Otherwise, starting LoginActivity every time and passing to MainActivity (or whatever) seems just a waste. "Waste" not in the sense of performance, but of clarity of your app.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution for you is to add a SplashScreen or like a "fake" screen.
Here you check if he's logged in already and based on it you start the correct activity.

Maybe the absolutely best way would be to do it with fragments, but you have to change a lot of your app.

About when to call it, the onCreate is perfect :)